# Como dividir uma string em MySQL?

Tags: mysql

O meu banco de dados MySQL contém uma tabela `t_usuario` com uma coluna `nome`, onde há um registro com o nome `Gustavo Henrique Almeida Martins`.

Como posso fazer um `SELECT` para retornar apenas o nome `Gustavo`?

| id_usuario | nome |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Gustavo Henrique Almeida Martins |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar a função [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index).

O primeiro parâmetro é o valor que você deseja dividir, o segundo é por qual caractere a string será divida e o terceiro é qual dos valores cortados você deseja.

```
SELECT
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(NOME, ' ', 1) AS PrimeiroNome
FROM USUARIOS
```

<sup>[**Veja funcionando no SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1187d18/4/0)</sup>

Comment: Aqui deu certo. Valeu!

Comment: @GustavoMartins Por nada. Para constar: você pode aceitar a resposta que mais te ajudou marcando o **V** do lado esquerdo dela.

Comment: Quem votou contra poderia aproveitar e me dizer qual o problema? =D

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que vai ajudar:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(nomecompleto, ' ', 1), ' ', -1)  AS primeironome
    ,TRIM( SUBSTR(nomecompleto, LOCATE(' ', nomecompleto)) ) AS sobrenome 
FROM
    suatabela
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5662c/2)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]